# pytorch convert a conv2d layer to tensorrt results in fp16 != fp32

Tags: pytorch, onnx, tensorrt

I tried to convert a conv2d layer to TensorRT, and I found that with different params can result in different accuracy between fp16 and fp32. Anyone could give me some suggestions?

You can reproduce my result using following code,when changing line`in_chans, embed_dim, patch_HW = 3, 128, (14,14)` to `in_chans, embed_dim, patch_HW = 3, 384, (14,14)`

tensorrt version: 8.5.3.1
pytorch version: 1.13.1+cu117
cuda version: 12.1

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import onnx
import onnxruntime
import numpy as np
import tensorrt as trt
import pycuda.autoinit
import pycuda.driver
stream = pycuda.driver.Stream()

# define torch model
class test_conv2d_fp16_trt(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_chans, embed_dim, patch_HW):
        super().__init__()
        self.proj = nn.Conv2d(in_chans, embed_dim, kernel_size=patch_HW, stride=patch_HW)
        nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.proj.weight)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.proj(x)

# convert to onnx
def convert_to_onnx(x, torch_model, onnx_model_path):
    # Export the model
    torch.onnx.export(torch_model,               # model being run
                      x,                         # model input (or a tuple for multiple inputs)
                      onnx_model_path,   # where to save the model (can be a file or file-like object)
                      export_params=True,        # store the trained parameter weights inside the model file
                      opset_version=14,          # the ONNX version to export the model to
                      do_constant_folding=False,  # whether to execute constant folding for optimization
                      input_names = ['input'],   # the model's input names
                      output_names = ['output'], # the model's output names
                      dynamic_axes={'input' : {0 : 'batch_size'},    # variable length axes
                                    'output' : {0 : 'batch_size'}})

def to_numpy(tensor):
    return tensor.detach().cpu().numpy() if tensor.requires_grad else tensor.cpu().numpy()

def onnx_model_infer(x, onnx_model_path):
    onnx_model = onnx.load(onnx_model_path)
    onnx.checker.check_model(onnx_model)
    ort_session = onnxruntime.InferenceSession(onnx_model_path)

    # compute ONNX Runtime output prediction
    ort_inputs = {ort_session.get_inputs()[0].name: to_numpy(x)}
    ort_outs = ort_session.run(None, ort_inputs)
    return ort_outs[0]
    
def check_output_match(output1, output2):
    np.testing.assert_allclose(output1, output2, rtol=1e-03, atol=1e-05)

def build_trt_model(logger, input_path, output_path, input_shape, is_fp16):
    builder = trt.Builder(logger)
    config = builder.create_builder_config()
    profile = builder.create_optimization_profile()
    profile.set_shape(
        'input', min=input_shape,
        opt=input_shape,
        max=input_shape)
    config.add_optimization_profile(profile)
    config.max_workspace_size = 4 << 30
    config.min_timing_iterations = 1
    if is_fp16:
        config.flags = 1 << int(trt.BuilderFlag.FP16)
    
    network = builder.create_network(
        1 << int(trt.NetworkDefinitionCreationFlag.EXPLICIT_BATCH))
    with trt.OnnxParser(network, logger) as parser:
        with open(input_path, 'rb') as fp:
            parser.parse(fp.read())
            engine = builder.build_engine(network, config=config)
    
    assert engine != None
    with open(output_path, 'wb') as fp:
        fp.write(engine.serialize())
    
    print('TRT{} engine is built.'.format(' (fp16)' if is_fp16 else ''))

def test_trt_model(logger, trt_model_path, input_shape=(1,3,504,378), output_shape=(1,384,36,27)):
    with trt.Runtime(logger) as runtime, open(trt_model_path, 'rb') as fp:
        engine = runtime.deserialize_cuda_engine(fp.read())
    
    image = np.ones(input_shape, dtype=np.float32)
    image_data = np.ascontiguousarray(image).astype(np.float32)
    
    # prepare GPU memory buffer
    image_gdata = pycuda.driver.mem_alloc(image_data.nbytes)
    output_data = np.zeros(output_shape, np.float32)
    output_gdata = pycuda.driver.mem_alloc(output_data.nbytes)
    with engine.create_execution_context() as context:
        context.active_optimization_profile = 0
        context.set_binding_shape(0, image_data.shape)
    
        # run the network
        pycuda.driver.memcpy_htod_async(
            image_gdata, image_data, stream)
        context.execute_async_v2(
            bindings=[int(image_gdata), int(output_gdata)],
            stream_handle=stream.handle)
        pycuda.driver.memcpy_dtoh_async(
            output_data, output_gdata, stream)
        stream.synchronize()
    
    image_gdata.free()
    output_gdata.free()
    return output_data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # fixed params
    im_h, im_w = 504, 378
    input_shape = (1,3,504,378)
    
    onnx_model_path = "check_conv2d_128.onnx"
    trt_fp16_model_path = "check_conv2d_128_fp16.ts"
    trt_fp32_model_path = "check_conv2d_128_fp32.ts"

    # debug params
    in_chans, embed_dim, patch_HW = 3, 384, (14,14) # failed case
    # in_chans, embed_dim, patch_HW = 3, 128, (14,14) # success case
    output_shape=(input_shape[0], embed_dim, im_h//patch_HW[0], im_w//patch_HW[0])
    torch_model = test_conv2d_fp16_trt(in_chans, embed_dim, patch_HW)
    torch_model.eval()

    image = np.ones(input_shape, dtype=np.float32)
    x = torch.from_numpy(image)
    
    torch_output = to_numpy(torch_model(x))
    print("build onnx")
    convert_to_onnx(x, torch_model, onnx_model_path)
    onnx_output = onnx_model_infer(x, onnx_model_path)

    check_output_match(torch_output, onnx_output)
    print("torch_output match onnx_output success!")

    logger = trt.Logger(trt.Logger.WARNING)
    print("build trt")
    build_trt_model(logger, onnx_model_path, trt_fp16_model_path, input_shape=input_shape, is_fp16=True)
    build_trt_model(logger, onnx_model_path, trt_fp32_model_path, input_shape=input_shape, is_fp16=False)

    trt_fp16_output = test_trt_model(logger, trt_fp16_model_path, input_shape=input_shape, output_shape=output_shape)
    trt_fp32_output = test_trt_model(logger, trt_fp32_model_path, input_shape=input_shape, output_shape=output_shape)

    check_output_match(onnx_output, trt_fp32_output)
    print("trt_fp32_output match onnx_output success!")

    check_output_match(trt_fp16_output, trt_fp32_output)
    print("trt_fp16_output match trt_fp32_output success!")
```

Comment: To clarify, the issue is that the outputs in fp32 and fp16 modes are different?

Comment: yes, at least I need them to pass the np.testing.assert_allclose(output1, output2, rtol=1e-03, atol=1e-05), but the most confusing thing is that the output channel number of conv2d will affect it.

Comment: When you convert to fp16, you inherently loose precision. Because neural networks are non-linear, small differences in the first layers can grow to become large differences in the output. For best results, you should retrain your model in fp16 mode and only then convert

Comment: thank you~I will try retrain model in fp16.